# How to replace %pdf% from !line! in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a script in which I need to use test similar to [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) (Boolean Test "does string exist ?"). In the example in manual, there is used normal %variable%, but I have Enabled Delayed Expansion. In my code I need to remove %pdf% from !line! .
My intention was to do it similar like in the [link](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) (Examples, SET _endbit, where %variable% is used)

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "source=GEN 0 GENERAL.html"
set "pdf=0_1_en.pdf"
echo In file:%source%
echo Look for anchor:%pdf%

rem Process each line in %source% file:
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%c in ("%source%") do (
   set "line=%%c"
   rem Test if the line contain a pdf file I look for

     echo on
     cls     
     echo Line: !line!
     REM PROBLEM HERE WITH VARIABLE !line! ? Need to replace %pdf% in !line!
   CALL SET "pdfline=%%line:%pdf%=%%"

   if not "!pdfline!" == "!line!" (
      echo Line: !line!
      CALL SET tagline=%%tagline:%pdf%=%%
      echo ACTUAL LINE: %tagline%
      pause
   )
)
pause
```

The key is on line 17, where I want to remove the pdf file from the variable. Can you help?

The script searches certain text in html file. The text is set to pdf filename. You can test it on any html file if you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the value of %pdf% from the line, then use this

```
set "pdfline=!line:%pdf%=!"
```

If you want to remove the literal string "%pdf%" from the line, then use this

```
set "pdfline=!line:%%pdf%%=!"
```